# Psychology and sociology in my Earth Changing underwater community

Tags: society, psychology, underwater, post-scarcity

I've [built a device](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/concealing-my-earth-changing-invention). It can change matter to energy and energy to matter with 100% efficiency. I've built myself a global presence, and populated the ranks of my employees with people such that I can solve [pretty much any problem](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29330/my-earth-changing-invention-how-can-i-hire-the-people-i-need?lq=1).

I want somewhere safe and secure to co-ordinate my empire from in case of [catastrophe](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29995/if-i-reveal-my-earth-changing-invention-suddenly-will-the-energy-material-or-fo?noredirect=1#comment80000_29995), but it seems that [space is a no-go](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30472/can-i-use-my-earth-changing-invention-to-hide-in-orbit), so instead I've settled for an underwater empire. It's perfect. Isolated, hard to detect or destroy, and surrounded by [raw materia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water)l I can use. Even if the world above goes to hell, me and my people will be safe.

I've selected about 500 of my people (all civilians, with no training for this kind of thing)) to descend with me to the stygian depths of my [Mariana Trench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariana_Trench) colony (other suggestions for location are welcomed), but now I'm worried. It will be ~6 months between surface resupply missions, and although I've got communications to the surface sorted and I can make any material I need, I'm not a psychologist. So:

**What psychological/sociological issues should I consider when designing my underwater base, and how best can I mitigate them given that I have unlimited resources but want to stay unnoticed?**

*Please note:* Assume I can build pretty much any superstructure I want. Between my machine and my Genius Intellect I'm confident we can solve any engineering issues that come with the deep sea. Bear in mind, however, that I want to be as hard to detect as possible (I'm getting paranoid about the Guv'mints).

Answer (score 1):

Being holed up in pitch darkness for months at a time, with practically no escape route if anything springs a leak, will put people on edge. They'll need a wide variety of recreational or stress-relief activities. Game rooms and sports teams will help. [Natural-feeling light also comes quickly to mind,](http://humanspaces.com/2014/10/08/this-is-the-headline-for-an-article-which-could-go-onto-two-lines/) instead of just putting up those bluish fluorescent lights everywhere. Basically take ideas from the big companies that shower their employees with benefits.