# Is depicting scenes of sub-FTL deep space travel with burning engines accurate?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, space, space-travel, spaceships

I've seen many sci-fi scenes that feature a ship underway on a deep space journey. As the ship passes the vantage point we can see engines burning during sub-FTL speeds (The Expanse most recently).

**Why would engines need to burn once target velocity is reached?**

Is there resistance in the vacuum of space that would slow velocity, or is the ship implied to be under constant acceleration? Wouldn't the trajectory continue at the same speed and direction without needing engine assistance?

Comment: While people here can answer, perhaps you should ask this in [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Do you want to know reasons to explain why this might be the case (i can think of a couple) or just assurance that you are right that this doesn't have to be this way ? The thing is you can easily come up with a reasons for burning engines, and you are asking about  fiction in general  - you can't say this is wrong without a concrete example.

Comment: @Raditz_35 since he mentions the TV show *The Expanse*, it's more about what screenwriters do instead of actual science.

Comment: @RonJohn This would be better suited for movie or scififa se then if it's specifically about one show. But currently I don't understand it as him asking exclusively about the expanse

Comment: @Raditz_35 good point about being OT.

Comment: Well, I asked [a question on constant-burn transfer orbits to maintain artificial gravity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34938/does-an-arbitrary-constant-burn-path-between-two-orbiting-bodies-exist). It may be of interest.

Comment: Remember [Newton's first law:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton's_third_law) an object in motion stays in motion until acted upon by another force.  Yes, there's dust in the universe that would cause drag, but it's miniscule and irrelevant (if dark matter exists then it may be something more than miniscule, but still pretty much irrelevant).  Of course, you have everything from nebula to asteroid fields that can cause drag.  But in space, pretty much nothing.  Juice it up and coast (almost) forever.

Comment: Force equal to mass times acceleration, so your engine have to burn fuel to gain speed (acceleration). Your mass would decrease because you are converting fuel into heat and other things. Your speed is constant unless act upon by outside forces such as gravitational pull of massive object such as deathstar, etc.

Comment: see [Deep Space 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_1) for a real example.  Engine was firing for 670 days.

Comment: @nzaman Really this could go in Physics, Space Exploration, here (because it's a common subject for building a world), or maybe even SciFi. Any of those places could answer it and benefit from having it seen there, so I don't think it's a problem to let it stay.

Comment: Considering *The Expanse* in particular it is worth keeping in mind that the Rocinante is not only a military ship but a class of ships for which high delta-V is a design goal. In the books we see or hear about quite a few ships that  make most of their journeys on free-fall trajectories.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Until you get up into relativistic velocities, how much you burn is only constrained by fuel. *The Expanse* provides a good example. They have handwaved super-high Isp engines. Since there's no compelling reason to conserve fuel, the fastest way to get from one place to another is to accelerate up to the halfway point (more or less), then flip for a deceleration burn all the way to the destination. If there's a need to conserve fuel, then break it up into distinct burns and coast in between. In *The Expanse*, it's handy because they can cruise at 1g acceleration and use the engines for artificial gravity. They only have to deal with zero g during the flip maneuver or when docked.

If you care about relativistic speeds, you probably don't want to keep burning past about 0.7 or 0.8c. See this [cool chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Derivation_and_Formulation). At around this point, more acceleration is starting to increase the time dilation effect and you are losing out on actually getting anywhere faster. You can keep burning if speed is critical, but your losses in terms of fuel consumption will start to eat you alive. So a long burn and coasting at low relativistic velocities would be the way to go if you are doing far future sci-fi.

Comment: In the Expanse book series maintaining artificial gravity is one of the main reasons the ships stay under constant burn: It's not just about getting places fast. In fact there's more than one instance of them flying their ships around in a big 'ol circle just to maintain gravity.

Comment: This is an awesome answer.

Comment: Fuel consumption would eat you alive only if you cared about actually increasing speed in the galactic reference frame. If the reason you're accelerating is to maintain 1g in the local reference frame, it might make sense to keep the engines on, even if has negligible impact on your galactic reference frame speed.

Comment: @R.M. That's a good point! I wasn't thinking past a race to the McGuffin.

Comment: Note that relativistic time dilation only applies to outside observers.  To the people on the ship, it will appear that they do get there faster.

Comment: "how much you burn is only constrained by fuel." Actually, for rockets, reaction mass is more of a constraint than fuel.

Comment: "At around this point, more acceleration is starting to increase the time dilation effect and you are losing out on actually getting anywhere faster." I'm not sure that's true: for one thing, it's speed that matters; for another, even if you experience time dilation, that just means that it appears to you that the journey takes less time. It doesn't actually slow you down.

Comment: On the other hand you kinda want good time dilation for long space flights as it cuts down on the other consumables.

Comment: @jamesqf: not only faster, but using less fuel, from your own perspective.

Comment: @MParm You should add a bit addressing the topic of drag in space, it's the only part of the original question you missed.

Comment: @Acccumulation The reaction mass *is* the fuel...

Comment: @immibis The fuel is used as reaction mass, but there is a distinction. Using a fuel with 100x the energy density would mean that you have 100x the fuel, but the same reaction mass.

Answer (score 11):

Continuous high ISP small engines are a great way to travel.

If your engines have *more* power than you need to get to your destination in the time you want, and the ISP response to power rate is flat, a short strong burn followed by coasting will be slighly more fuel efficient than a long weak burn.

On the other hand, if engine efficiency goes down as its output goes up by any decent margine, a long slow burn will remain more efficient than a fast short burn.

Current space rockets do fast short burns because our technology doesn't really give us good slow efficient burn options.  This is beginning to change with our ion engine technology.

A craft with high efficiency low-power engines and low efficiency high-power engines would want to continuously burn the low-power engines to get somewhere fast.

A craft where their engines exceed 1 g of thrust will want to continuously burn rather than burn stronger just for passenger comfort.

The distance you travel is the integral of your speed.  Long burns are slopes, fast burns are steeper slopes, and coasting is a line.  Based on the burn-speed to efficiency curve, you can work out how fast or slow a burn you'd want for a given distance profile.

In theory orbits and the movement of your target also factor into it; with orbits, often you want to put all of your thrust into a short window based on orbital geometry (apogee, perigee, or the nodes of a Hohmann transfer orbit).

So there are lots of reasons why you'd have short burns, and lots of reasons you'd have long burns.

Comment: +1 for mentioning real life ion engines.

Comment: "Current space rockets do fast short burns because our technology doesn't really give us good slow efficient burn options." That's not really true - stronger rockets are much more efficient when you're worrying about getting into orbit, so there's just a lot of incentive to develop rockets like that first.

Comment: "a short strong burn followed by coasting will be slighly more fuel efficient than a long weak burn." A _lot_ more efficient if there is a massive planet nearby. See Oberth effect.

Answer (score 6):

It's not accurate, as you already surmise.

Those big burners at the back strongly suggest the ships fly by pushing out reaction mass backwards to get thrust forwards. Even with future tech in mind, you're stuck with the tyranny of the rocket equation. Basically, as you go for higher speeds, you need more and more reaction mass to accelerate and decelerate, which makes your ship heavier, so you need bigger engines and more fuel, until your ship is one giant fuel tank with and engine and cabin strapped to it.

Given that, it simply doesn't make sense to go faster and burn longer than you absolutely need to. A military ship on a short range intercept mission would likely do this, but if it burned non-stop for 30 days in deep space, it would *also* take 30 days to undo that burn if the situation changed, so the faster it went the more it would be locked into one course.

### Flying backwards

Assuming future tech somehow discovered a way for ships to have/get unlimited fuel/reaction mass (maybe siphoning it from an alterante dimension in-flight?), they would still do things quite differently from the way depicted in the movies.

Any ship approaching a planet or other non-accelerating object would fly (and burn) normally at first but then halfway it would turn around, point the engines forward and slow down. For an accelerating target like another ship, the goal would be to match velocities or in battle to at least slow down enough to be in range of the target for more than 1-2 seconds. That means burning retro, left, right, up, down, basically any way except forward until you're behind them.

Mounting multiple sets of engines in the various directions would just make the ship heavier and slower, so there will always be main engines in one direction, with small extras for quick and unpredictable moves.

### Movies would suck

Of course, orbital maneuvers and the specifics of deep space navigation are so alien to the average movie viewer that entertainment value overrules realism even if the makers know how it should look. The feeling movies aim for is often WW2 fighter planes. bombers and battleships. Those are familiar, there's lots of action and its within easy visual range, so that's what movie spaceships look and move like.

Comment: You don't need unlimited fuel, the extra fuel must only be cheaper than the benefit from burning engines is worth to whoever pays for it. Might sound like a nitpick, but this changes the character from "very unreasonable to "situationally accurate"

Comment: It's not so much the cost of the fuel (actually reaction mass), it's all the extra mass you need to accelerate and decelerate, which costs more fuel again, etc. Unless of course reactionless thrust is a thing, then you don't need those big burners at the back anyway.

Comment: Your edit basically describes how this works in The Expanse.

Comment: Yeah, love that series, and they get a lot closer to realistic there, though the fights get conveniently short range every time thanks to stealth and surprise. The first big fight is basically considered over after they fire a bunch of torpedoes at long range, but then the spoilers happen...

Comment: You don't need to suck reaction mass from an alternate dimension: there's hydrogen floating around. See Bussard ramjet.

Comment: I remember from another post here that they were shown to not actually produce any net benefit.

Answer (score 5):

While traveling long distances all energy given to the engines effects apparent travel time equally.

A little push over a long time rather than a big shove and coast for a long time is a reasonable engineering trade-off, in fact our current most fuel efficient engines are good at providing a little thrust over a long time. If you have the (unreasonable) energy required to accelerate a ship to fractions of c keeping the humans comfortable with a steady acceleration is probably a better choice than smashing them on launch and then letting them float. It also requires less power (smaller engines) to do a long (relatively) light burn than a short heavy one.

If the ship has power though the whole flight (temperature above 3 K, light) you probably can afford to give some to the engines.

There is interstellar mass that would slow you down eventually; something like 10$^{-7}$g per m$^2$ of cross section per light-year, but that's not really enough to worry about.

Answer (score -1):

> Why would engines need to burn once target velocity is reached?

Because screenwriters:

1. aren't very educated in science, and
2. assume that moviegoers are stupid.

> Wouldn't the trajectory continue at the same speed and direction without needing engine assistance?

Correct.  But movies don't deal in reality.

Comment: Not true in case of Expanse, where constant burn provides 1g and makes travel shorter than short burn, passive flight mode.

Comment: @Mołot In that case, "*target velocity is **not** reached*", since you're under constant acceleration.  (ISTM a *lot* of your mass would be fuel.  Doesn't sound very efficient.)

Comment: this particular show is explicitly mentioned in the question and in the show (season two) it is explicitly explained that they solved issue of efficiency. Handwavium, yes, but they pointed at it and pretty much said "this is what we are handwaving".

Comment: Yes it requires some handwaving as to how to make an engine efficient enough that it's feasible for that level of acceleration, but for sci-fi that's pretty realistic.  The principle is not only possible, but is in use in modern spacecraft in the form of ion engines such as the one used on the Dawn mission.  Dawn is much smaller than any ship in the Expanse, and accelerated at 90 mN instead of ~1g, but by keeping it's engines running for hundreds of days it was able to visit Ceres and Vesta.

Comment: @Nick those low-thrust ion engines are what I was thinking of too, which is why I didn't mention them.  Also, they don't "burn".